# reading via matlab a number after a specific string in a txt file

Tags: matlab

I re explain my pb in a large a.txt file i have

Amount of Food is 1

Desired Travel is 5

I need to read the 1 after the 'Amount of Food is ' expression and the 5 after the 'Desired Travel is' expression, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html): with regexpi you can simply look for numbers in your strings.

The syntax is as simple as this:

```
startIndex = regexpi(str,expression)
```

where the `expression` parameter is a regex expression (i.e. '\d*' to retrieve consecutive digits).

Comment: Sorry i re explain my problem i want to read in a.txt file this two number

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case a way to perform this with regular expressions would be:

First you have to decide what strings are valid in your search
for example:

```
firstpar = 'First parameter is [0-9]+';
```

means that you are looking for a string *'First parameter is '*
that ends with a **sequence of digits**.

Then you could use `regexp` or `regexpi` in the following way:

```
results = regexp(mystring, firstpar, 'match');
```

Where `mystring` is the text you perform the search on and `'match'` means that you want parts of the text as output, not indexes.

Now, `results` is a cell matrix with each cell containing a string that appeared in your text and fulfilled your `firstpar` definition. In order to extract just the numbers from cell matrix of strings you could use `regexp` again, but now helping yourself with `cellfun`, which iteratively applies your command to all cells of a cell matrix:

```
numbers = cellfun(@(x) str2num(regexp(x, '[0-9]+', 'match', 'once')), results);
```

`numbers` is an array of numbers that you were looking for.

You can do the same for different string patterns - if you want to have a more general string definitions (instead of straightforward `firstpar` that we used here) read [matlab documentation about regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html) (alexcasalboni pasted it in his comment), scroll down to Input Arguments and expand 'expressions'.

The difference between `regexp` and `regexpi` is that the latter is case insensitive.